# Getting Error after run deploy command

Tags: magento-2.2.1

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: include(/home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/generated/metadata/frontend.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 31

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: include(/home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/generated/metadata/frontend.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 31
#0 /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php(31): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'include(/home/m...', '/home/milkezuq/...', 31, Array)
#1 /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php(31): include()
#2 /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(132): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader\Compiled->load('frontend')
#3 /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#4 /home/milkezuq/public_html/magetest/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#5 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue of ObjectManager and Factory method from generated directory to resolve it Follow below steps :

**run below commands in sequence** :

1. rm -rf generated
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
5. php bin/magento cache:clean
6. php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: As you said I run given commands in sequence. But nothing happened

Comment: It runs successfully after removing generated directory . But it is not good idea.

Comment: @RajeshKumar - No it is good way - as generated directory always generates again , when you run `setup:di:compile` again and when you refresh your page. its auto generated directory so there is no issue

Comment: Now I again run these commands in given sequence. And it runs perfectly. Thanks a lot @Manthan Dave

Comment: @RajeshKumar - Thanks !! Happy to help and keep helping :)